# In Nautilus, how do we make sure that the current device used shows up?

Tags: history, nautilus

I would like to always see the current device at the top of a window. It is in the history at the top, but Nautilus sometimes only show the last fragments in the path - the device is hidden.  So, I have to click with the mouse to move the history toward the left to see the device. Is there some configuration setting that will guarantee that we always see the device. I feel it is kind of important, because I mount very similar remote file systems on my local machine - the only obvious difference is the name of the device where they are mounted. I hate to always have to click on the history to make sure that I am on the right one.